# javascript exclude some values in average calc

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Here are some data:

```
data = [
 {"Age":26,"Level":8},
 {"Age":37,"Level":9},
 {"Age":null,"Level":15},
 {"Age":null,"Level":45}
];
```

from which I'm trying to calculate average for their properties:

```
var avg = {};
  var rows = data.length;
  data.forEach(obj => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
        if(obj[k] != null){
          avg[k] = (avg[k] || 0) + obj[k] / rows;
        }
      });
    });

  return avg;
```

but the problem is in items that has properties with `null` values, where I'm trying to exclude `null` values from the calculation, and if you take a look at the the [codepen](https://codepen.io/cwebster750/pen/KLZBoo) there is Age: **15.75** instead of **31.5**
because length of the data is always 4 (and should be 2 since 2 of them are `null`). How would be the best way to get the length to not be including the `null`s?

Comment: What if all the ages are null?  What do you want to have happen then?

Comment: Probably write null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the sum and count for every key independently.

```js
var data = [{ "Age": 26, "Level": 8 }, { "Age": 37, "Level": 9 }, { "Age": null, "Level": 15 }, { "Age": null, "Level": 45 }],
    avg = {},
    temp = {};

data.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    if (obj[k] === null) return;
    temp[k] = temp[k] || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
    temp[k].sum += obj[k];
    temp[k].count++;
    avg[k] = temp[k].sum / temp[k].count;
}));

console.log(avg);
console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't like how this recalculates the average every time it increments the count.  This is why I need to buy a faster laptop every few years.

Comment: @Wyck, you could move the calculation outside of the loop. no need to buy a new laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to get the `sum` and `count` for each non-null item. You can add a [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) property to automatically calculate the average based on the `sum` and the `count` properties in the counter

```js
const data = [{Age:26,Level:8},{Age:37,Level:9},{Age:null,Level:15},{Age:null,Level:45}];

let counter = {}

for (const item of data) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (item[key] !== null) {
        counter[key] = counter[key] || {
          sum: 0,
          count: 0,
          get average() { return this.sum/this.count }
        };
        counter[key].sum += item[key]
        counter[key].count++
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an object with nested object which has two properties `value` and `count`

```js
const data = [
 {"Age":26,"Level":8},
 {"Age":37,"Level":9},
 {"Age":null,"Level":15},
 {"Age":null,"Level":45}
];

let avg = {}

data.forEach(x => {
  for(let k in x){
    if(!avg[k]){
      avg[k] = {value:0,count:0};
    }
    if(x[k] !== null){
      avg[k].value += x[k]
      avg[k].count++;
    }
  }
})

avg = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(avg).map(([k,v]) => ([k,v.value/v.count])))

console.log(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
 {"Age": 26, "Level": 8},
 {"Age": 37, "Level": 9},
 {"Age": null, "Level": 15},
 {"Age": null, "Level": 45}
];

let averages = data.reduce((values, o) => {
 Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  if (v !== null)
   values[k] = (values[k] || []).concat(v);
 });
 return values;
}, {});

Object.entries(averages).forEach(([k, vs]) =>
 averages[k] = vs.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / vs.length);

console.log(averages);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this: (not tested yet)

```
var data = [
    {"Age":26,"Level":8},
    {"Age":37,"Level":9},
    {"Age":null,"Level":15},
    {"Age":null,"Level":45}
];

var sum = { "Age": 0, "Level": 0 };
var average = { "Age": 0, "Level": 0 };
var sumCount = { "Age": 0, "Level": 0 };

// sum up all objects
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Object.keys(data[i]).forEach(function (key) {
        if (data[i][key] == null || data[i][key] == undefined)
            return;
        sumCount[key]++;
        sum[key] = sum[key] + data[i][key];
    });
}

// make average object
Object.keys(average).forEach(function (key) {
    average[key] = sum[key] / sumCount[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in a relatively concise manner with just [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and inside of it just iterate over the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var data = [ {"Age":26,"Level":8}, {"Age":37,"Level":9}, {"Age":null,"Level":15}, {"Age":null,"Level":45} ];

let result = data.reduce((r, c) => (Object.keys(c).forEach(k => {
    r[k] = (r[k] || { Sum: 0, Count: 0, Avg: 0 })
    r[k].Sum += c[k] || 0
    r[k].Count += c[k] ? 1 : 0
    r[k].Avg = r[k].Sum / r[k].Count
  }), r), {})

console.log(result)
```